# Hibernate Win7 via VBA [Excel]?

Tags: excel, hibernation, vba

I'm looking for a way to put my notebook [Win7] into hibernation via VBA [Excel 2010]. I was searching for a solution but couldnt find a handy one.
I was playing with the `SendKeys` method but no luck. Then the `Shell "C:\WINDOWS\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState", vbHide` gave me `Compile error: Invalid outside procedure` message. The `Function ExitWindowsEx` gives only the choices to log off, shut down and reboot but no hibernation as far as I know. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just successfully hibernated my comp. Here is the magnificent code:

```
Option Explicit

Declare Function SetSuspendState Lib "powrprof.dll" _
(ByVal Hibernate As Boolean, ByVal ForceCritical As Boolean, ByVal DisableWakeEvent As Boolean) As Boolean

Sub Yoo()
    Dim value_hibernate As Integer
    value_hibernate = SetSuspendState(True, False, False)
    If value_hibernate <> 1 Then MsgBox "Hibernation has failed."
End Sub
```

Some comments said that its better going with the `SetSuspendState` than the PowerState one.

Have fun hibernating your machines via VBA! Yaay!